# Amazon Rekognition usable with images hosted on other server/site than S3?

Tags: amazon-rekognition

do I understand the Documentation right and it's not possible to use the Amazon Rekognition service with "external" links without priorly save the images on Amazon S3 or another local server?

Why simple web hosted images are not supported?

Thanksf
fp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you’re sending blob data to Amazon. if you convert remote image file to base64 before sending, you can use remote files